# Imagick: Convert bash command to PHP-script

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

Running on PHP 7.2.33 with ImageMagick 6.8.9., I have the following ImageMagick bash command (which removes shadows from images):

```
convert image.jpg \( -clone 0 -blur 0x5 \) +swap -compose divide -composite result.png
```

What would the PHP, using iMagick, equivalent be?

This is how far I got..

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->readImage('image.jpg');
$im_clone = clone $im;
$im_clone->blurImage(0,5);
```

Comment: Look up compositeImage and do the divide of $im/$im_clone. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php

Comment: I note that the constant COMPOSITE_DIVIDE is not listed in the constants section. I do not know if that is just a documentation error. So I would try to use that and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks! What about +swap?

Comment: In command line A/B is `convert B A -compose divide -composite result`. I do not like that syntax. I like to have the order A B. So I swap the two and write `convert A B +swap -compose divide -composite result` In iMagick, the order is defined by compositeImage syntax. So just provide the images in the proper order. `$A->compositeImage($B, imagick::COMPOSITE_DIVIDE ... )` would be A/B.